# How do I add rotation angle to the marker using ng-app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am not able to add angle for rotation to the marker.
I want to calculate the angle between the current latitude longitude and next latitude longitude and accordingly place the car icon.
I tried adding rotation at the place were I am declaring the car and bike icons but that did not help.

HTML file:

```
    <div class="row" ng-controller="Admin">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <ng-map center="Pune India" zoom="13">
         <marker ng-repeat="v in selectedVehicles" icon="{{showIcon(v)}}"   
         position="{{markers[v.id]}}" on-click="showDetails(event, v)">    
        </marker>
     </ng-map>
    </div>
```

Javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('TripNShip');
app.controller('Admin', ['$scope','NgMap','Vehicle',
    function($scope,NgMap,Vehicle) {
    $scope.vehicles = Vehicle.all();
  $scope.selectedVehicles = [];
    var car_icon = {
    scaledSize: [60, 30],
    url: '<%= asset_path("car.svg") %>'
  };

  var bike_icon = {
    scaledSize: [60, 30],
    url: '<%= asset_path("bike.svg") %>'
  };

  $scope.showIcon = function(vehicle) {
    if (vehicle.v_type == "BIKE"){
      return bike_icon;
    } else {
      return car_icon;
    }
  };

  $scope.showVehicles = function(vehs){
    $scope.markers = {};
    $scope.selectedVehicles = vehs;
    var vehicles = vehs.map(function(v) {return v.id;});
    vehicles.forEach(function(id) {
      var source = new EventSource('/api/v1/vehicle_locations?vehicle_id=' + id);
      source.onmessage = function(event) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          if(vehicles.indexOf(data.vehicle_id) !== -1) {
            $scope.markers[id] = [data.lat, data.lon];
          }else{
            source.close();
          }
        });
      };
    }); 
  };

  $scope.showDetails = function(event, vehicle) {
    $scope.selectedVehicle = vehicle;
    $scope.map.showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow', this);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: You can try setting the `style` attribute of the marker tag with a css value for the rotation `style="transform: rotate(<<insert calculated value here>>);"`

Comment: This didn't work. I tried adding rotation to svg as well as jpg image.